# How do you push and pull columns on BOOTSTRAP 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, push, pull

I have tried these 2 options:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8 bg-danger">
```

and

```
<div class="col-md-4 order-md-8 bg-danger">
```

Neither is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code and link? Hope it will work for you.
In Bootstrap 5, `.offset-*-*` classes use for the set the offset.

Please refer to this link:
https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/s9qn4o71/4/

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Extra Example  -->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-8 bg-danger">col-md-4 offset-md-8</div>
</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3 bg-danger">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-3 bg-danger">.col-md-3 .offset-md-3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3 bg-danger">.col-md-6 .offset-md-3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```